# I have error in material UI tabs as "Failed prop type: The prop `children` is not supported. Please remove it"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm using Material UI tabs for the first time in my project, everything works fine but there is one error in console while running the project here is:

```
Failed prop type: The prop `children` is not supported. Please remove it
```

Here is my react index.js code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my TabSection file:

```
import { AppBar, Tab, Tabs } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import SyncCabinet from "../screens/SyncCabinet";
import ScheduleInfo from '../screens/ScheduleInfo';

class TabSection extends Component {

    handleCallToRouter = (value) => {
        this.props.history.push(value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Tabs
                    value={this.props.history.location.pathname}
                    onChange={this.handleCallToRouter}
                >
                    <Tab
                        label="Synchronize Cabinet"
                        value="/"
                    >
                        <div>
                            <SyncCabinet />
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab
                        label="Schedule Information"
                        value="/ScheduleInfo"
                    >
                        <div>
                            <ScheduleInfo />
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(TabSection);
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import Navbar from './screens/Navbar';
import Sidebar from './screens/Sidebar';
import SyncCabinet from './screens/SyncCabinet';
import './App.css';
import TabSection from './screens/TabSection';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <TabSection/>
      <div className="sidebar__syncandsche">
        <Sidebar />
        <SyncCabinet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I use Material UI Tabs. I'm trying to implement two components in two tabs respectively. Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting the Tab Renderer

The `Tab` element [does not allow](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#props) the `children` property.  In order to customize the rendering of the tab, you would set the [`component` prop](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/#props).  The value should be the component itself, ie. `{SyncCabinet}` instead of `{<SyncCabinet/>}`.

```
<Tab label="Synchronize Cabinet" value="/" component={SyncCabinet}/>
```

This would set `SyncCabinet` as the renderer *for the tab button*.

Your imports show that the components that you are trying to use as `children` here are from the `screens` folder, so I think that you are trying to set the contents of the *page* for that `Tab` rather than the contents of the tab button.

#### Setting the Tab Contents

I'm guessing that you are used to using some other UI library such as [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/tabs/) where each `Tab` declares the contents to show when it is clicked.  In [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/), the `Tabs` and `Tab` are **just the tab bar** and you use a separate component to control the contents.

The docs show creating a `TabPanel` function component that takes its `index`/`value` as a prop along with the current `index`/`value` for the `Tabs` and only renders its contents if the two match. Since you are using React Router to control the tab state, you could just use a `Switch` and `Route` instead.  It can be inside the `TabSection` or at the top level of your `App`.

The `onChange` callback of the `Tabs` component gets the value as the [second argument](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#props) after the `event`, so you need to change your `handleCallToRouter` arguments to `(event, value) =>` or just `(_, value) =>` (`_` is a convention for ignored arguments).

This code should work:

```
class _TabSection extends Component {
  handleCallToRouter = (_, value) => {
    this.props.history.push(value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Tabs
          value={this.props.history.location.pathname}
          onChange={this.handleCallToRouter}
        >
          <Tab label="Synchronize Cabinet" value="/" />
          <Tab label="Schedule Information" value="/ScheduleInfo" />
        </Tabs>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/ScheduleInfo" component={ScheduleInfo} />
          <Route path="/" component={SyncCabinet} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```